# linux gdal 3.1.0 ogr2ogr ERROR 1: Unable to find driver PostgreSQL

Tags: gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I have seen a number of posts similar to this but I have another issue. I try to complie gdal-3.1.0 to import osm.pbf to PostgreSQL. My os is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6. I need Oracle and PostgreSQL driver. Oracle is working but PostgreSQL throw error `Unable to find driver PostgreSQL`.
I install PostgreSQL client `libpqxx-devel-5.0.1-2.rhel7.1.x86_64` and set enviromen variables:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/sas/shared/devdi94/thirdparty/oracle/12.2.0.1/client/lib:/usr/pgsql-11/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/sas/shared/devdi94/thirdparty/oracle/12.2.0.1/client
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/pgsql-11/lib/pkgconfig

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH ORACLE_HOME PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Then, `./configure --with-threads --with-pg=yes --disable-static`
results looks good

```
OCI support:               yes
PostgreSQL support:        yes
```

`make & make install` Log is clear without errors.
Ogr2ogr is working for oracle but not for PostgreSQL

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='xxx' host='xxx' port='xxx' user='xxx' ACTIVE_SCHEMA='xxx' password='xxx'" "dolnoslaskie-latest.osm.pbf"
 
>>> ERROR 1: Unable to find driver `PostgreSQL'.
```

I don't know where the problem is. have I some missing library or enviroment variable?

---

I try install version gdal-3.0.1 and both drivers working. Maybe gdal-3.1.0 have bug.